# crear un table Layout ANDROID

Tags: android, android-studio

buenos días, me gustaría saber que método o que implementar para poder lograr algo similar a lo que muestra la imagen a continuación

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Fernando te sugiero revisar el [tour] y agrega lo que has investigado o el layout que has tratado o investigado, aquí te pueden ayudar si tus preguntas se crean en base a [ask], saludos

Comment: Hola para ellos te recomiendo que uses un recyclerview y el layout manager lo hagas GridLayoutManager y coloca la cantidad de columnas que vas a ocupar, siguiendo tu ejemplo serian 4, `miRecycler.setLayoutmanager=GridLayoutManager(this,4,false);`